# tf.reshape(self.normalized_price(prce), (-1, 1)), ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am getting the following error when I am calling the subclass of the model. My guess is that I am not passing the two parameters correctly or the reshape is not outputting the correct value.

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for '{{node base_stock_model/concat}} = ConcatV2[N=3, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](base_stock_model/sequential_2/embedding_2/embedding_lookup/Identity_1, base_stock_model/sequential_3/embedding_3/embedding_lookup/Identity_1, base_stock_model/Reshape, base_stock_model/concat/axis)' with input shapes: [32], [32], [1,1], [].
```

Here is the main class model

```
class StockModel(tfrs.models.Model):

  def __init__(self, rating_weight: float, retrieval_weight: float) -> None:

    super().__init__()

    embedding_dimension = 32

    self.user_model= UserModel()


    self.stock_model= base_stockModel()    

  
    self.rating_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
    ])

    # The tasks.
    self.rating_task: tf.keras.layers.Layer = tfrs.tasks.Ranking(
        loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()],
    )
    self.retrieval_task: tf.keras.layers.Layer = tfrs.tasks.Retrieval(
        metrics=tfrs.metrics.FactorizedTopK(
            candidates=stocks.batch(1).map(self.stock_model)
        )
    )

    # The loss weights.
    self.rating_weight = rating_weight
    self.retrieval_weight = retrieval_weight

  def call(self, features: Dict[Text, tf.Tensor]) -> tf.Tensor:

    user_embeddings = self.user_model(features['username'])

    # np.array([features["name"],features["price"]])
    
    price=tf.as_string(features["price"])
 
    stock_embeddings = self.stock_model([features["name"],price])
    
    return (
        user_embeddings,
        stock_embeddings,
        self.rating_model(
            tf.concat([user_embeddings, stock_embeddings], axis=1)
        ),
    )
  def compute_loss(self, features: Dict[Text, tf.Tensor], training=False) -> tf.Tensor:

    ratings = features.pop("Rating")

    print("features",features)

    user_embeddings, stock_embeddings, rating_predictions = self(features)

    # We compute the loss for each task.
    rating_loss = self.rating_task(
        labels=ratings,
        predictions=rating_predictions,
    )
    retrieval_loss = self.retrieval_task(user_embeddings, stock_embeddings)

    # And combine them using the loss weights.
    return (self.rating_weight * rating_loss
            + self.retrieval_weight * retrieval_loss)
```

The above main class model calls the base_stockModel class, which is causing errors.

```
class base_stockModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      embedding_dimension=32
      self.stock_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
        vocabulary=unique_stock_titles, mask_token=None),
      tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(unique_stock_titles) + 1, embedding_dimension)
      ])
      self.price_embedding=tf.keras.Sequential([
          tf.keras.layers.Discretization(prices_bucket.tolist()),
          tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(prices_bucket)+2,32)
      ])
      self.normalized_price = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=None)
      self.normalized_price.adapt(prices)

  
  def call(self,input,*args,**kwargs):
    print(input.get_shape(),kwargs)
    # print(tf.rank(input),[input[:]],input.get_shape(),input.dtype)
    # nme=input[3]
    nme=input[0]
    prce=input[1]

    prce=tf.strings.to_number(input[1],out_type=tf.dtypes.float32)
#print(tf.rank(self.stock_embedding(nme)),tf.rank(self.price_embedding(prce)),tf.rank(tf.reshape(sself.normalized_price(prce), (-1, 1))))
    return tf.concat([
        self.stock_embedding(nme),
        self.price_embedding(prce),
        tf.reshape(self.normalized_price(prce), (-1, 1)),
    ], axis=1)
```

This code is a variant of tensorflow recommender official page https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/multitask/
https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/context_features
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First I analyzed all the ranks of input tensor. If they were not the same rank  model wants then we have to use tf.reshape() command or adjust the input to match model's demand. Note that, tf.shape() gives you the shape while running the model.

Here is documentation on it.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape